# Trac - Change ticket creation and closing date

Tags: trac, ticket-system

Is there a way to change creation and closing date for a ticket ?

Every week I export a report of all created/closed tickets and I need to change date for some of them.

Comment: but why would you want to do that? I feel this could be needed to answer your question conveniently.

Comment: As I wrote in the question I export reports (closed/created ticket per day) every Friday. If a day I forget to close a ticket I would like to set the closing date to have it in the right "place" in my report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creation and closing time of a ticket should not be changed. This is the start and the end of a workflow of a ticket.

If you need to get more information in your reports, rethink the ticket's workflow. Trac provides you a workflow,

http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracWorkflow

but you can customise it easily according to your needs through trac.ini.

In the case however you want to hack it, everything is in the trac database and you can change anything by hand, but don't go there.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change creation date at all, if you define it as the time the ticket is created.

Closing is the act of marking a ticket as resolved (last), so this could be manipulated at least by opening and closing a ticket again.